# Javascript function calling inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I googled a lot but no find a satisfying answer. Searching for a typing error in typescript faced the such code:

```
// @strict: false
let suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];

function pickCard(x: any): any {
  // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
  // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
  if (typeof x == "object") {
    let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
    return pickedCard;
  }
  // Otherwise just let them pick the card
  else if (typeof x == "number") {
    let pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13);
    return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 };
  }
}

let myDeck = [
  { suit: "diamonds", card: 2 },
  { suit: "spades", card: 10 },
  { suit: "hearts", card: 4 },
];

let pickedCard1 = myDeck[pickCard(myDeck)];  //<--- HERE IS DOUBT
alert("card: " + pickedCard1.card + " of " + pickedCard1.suit);

let pickedCard2 = pickCard(15);
alert("card: " + pickedCard2.card + " of " + pickedCard2.suit);
```

I like to understand what such an expression is that? Am i calling a function inside an array of objects passing that array as a parameter? That's correct? And Why a cant call the function straight like this:

```
let pickedCard1 = pickCard(myDeck);
```

Always I do i got undefined as return. Sorry the jr question but i am trying to understand javascript better.Thanks guys

Comment: If you `return x[pickedCard]` from the function, you can do `let pickedCard1 = pickCard(myDeck)`

Comment: `myDeck` is an object, so `pickCard(myDeck)` will return a number, and `myDeck[pickCard(myDeck)]` will be a card from the deck (like `{ suit: "diamonds", card: 2 }`, for instance).  Note that since you use `any` in your parameter types and return types, you are not getting much help from typescript.

Comment: Wow, i really thank you, i could understand what was happens here. At first time I see the code I got totally stuck. Really thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that you've left something off of your `object` branch - you're returning `number` instead of a `Card`:

```js
let pickedCard: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
// This is really `pickedCardIndex`
```

Instead, check that the passed in value is an Array using `Array.isArray` and then index out of the array as your last step:

```js
  if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    let pickedCardIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
    return x[pickedCardIndex];
  }
```

Comment: Wow, i really thank you, i could understand what was happens here. At first time I see the code I got totally stuck. Really thanks for the help.